# T-SQL: Rows to Columns

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am a SQL beginner, so can anyone please help me with this?

I have a table like this

```
YearMonth | Customer | Currency | BusinessType | Amount
04-2020   | 123      | EUR      | Budget       | 500
04-2020   | 123      | EUR      | Forecast     | 300
04-2020   | 123      | EUR      | Sales        | 700
```

And now I need it like:

```
YearMonth | Customer | Currency | Amount Budget | Amount Forecast | Amount Sales  
04-2020   | 123      | EUR      | 500           | 300             | 700
```

Is something like this possible?
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Without any explanation of how you get from input to output we are left guessing at a lot of things. Are there other business types? Are you totaling values for each month? Are there other months? Or customers? ...

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select yearmonth, customer, currency,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Budget' then amount end) as budget,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Forecast' then amount end) as forecast,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Sales' then amount end) as sales
from t
group by yearmonth, customer, currency;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can do aggregation :

```
select yearmonth, customer, currency,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'budget' then amount else 0 end),
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Forecast' then amount else 0 end),
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Sales' then amount else 0 end) 
from table t
group by yearmonth, customer, currency;
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Also, you may want to add an "Other" to capture any new Business Types:

```
select yearmonth, customer, currency,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Budget' then amount end) as budget,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Forecast' then amount end) as forecast,
       sum(case when businesstype = 'Sales' then amount end) as sales,
       sum(case when businesstype not in ('Budget', 'Forecast', 'Sales') then amount end) as other
from t
group by yearmonth, customer, currency;
```

Answer (score 0):

This type of requirements are usually resolved using T-SQL PIVOT relational operation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver15). For the above example I used the following query to achieve this:

```
-- Create a temporary table to store the data.
IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##temp2') IS NOT NULL) DROP TABLE ##temp2
CREATE TABLE ##temp2 (Id int IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY, YearMonth varchar(100), Customer int, Currency varchar(100), BusinessType varchar(100), Amount int)
INSERT ##temp2
VALUES
('04-2020', 123,'EUR','Sales', 700),
('04-2020', 123,'EUR','Budget', 500),
('04-2020', 123,'EUR','Forecast', 300)
-- Using PIVOT allows you to move rows into columns
SELECT  pivot_table.YearMonth,
        pivot_table.Customer,
        pivot_table.Currency,
        [Amount Forecast] = pivot_table.Forecast,
        [Amount Budget] = pivot_table.Budget,
        [Amount Sales] = pivot_table.Sales
FROM
        (
            SELECT  YearMonth,
                    Customer,
                    Currency,
                    BusinessType,
                    Amount
            FROM    ##temp2
        ) t
PIVOT
(
    SUM(Amount)
    FOR BusinessType IN ([Sales], [Budget], [Forecast])
) AS pivot_table;
```